# How do I fix the http 500 bad gatway when delploying Docker to GCP App Engine?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, google-app-engine

> I want to deploy my spring boot app in a docker component to gcp App Engine
> When I run the docker componet local I get access to the web site.
> When I deploy the component to the gcp app engine with the command gcloud app deploy
> I get a http error 502 Bad Gateway nginx
> The Docker file look like this

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk14
MAINTAINER steinko
VOLUME /tmp
COPY build/libs/atm.jar ./
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["-jar", "/atm.jar"]
EXPOSE 4001
```

> The app.yaml files looks like this

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
service: atm
```

> How do I fix this error?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If so, please verify it

Answer (score 0):

According to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build): The App Engine front end will route incoming requests to the appropriate module on port 8080. You must be sure that your application code is listening on 8080. Also, it looks like the FROM should be one of Google's base image, also in that document.